How to Subtract Objects in jq?
We can merge two objects recursively with * operator. For example like this: jq '.[0] * .[1]' -s a.json b.json. The only problem (I realized) with it is it doesn't merge the arrays. But some guys did it.

What I want is the opposite. Assuming the things in b.json are always exist in a.json; a.json, b.json and the result respectively:
{
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "js/background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage"
  ]
}

{
  "background": {
    "type": "module"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "unlimitedStorage"
  ]
}

{
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "js/background.js"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ]
}

There are some questions on Stack Overflow like this but they are specific cases. I rather have a generic one like the meld function.

I tried to edit the meld function but couldn't achieve anything worth to mention.

Re "it doesn't merge the arrays": Because there's no canonical way of doing it. Merging arrays could mean simply appending one to the other, or overwriting items at same indices, or performing more complex operations like (recursively?) matching their contents. Your subtraction faces the same pitfalls when aiming for a "generic" solution. How to perform what you want in a recursive way, i.e. if the array items are not just strings but complex structures that match in some parts but not in others?

IDK about others but when I hear merging arrays it should be either add one to the other or add the difference in them, so do a union operation. I know it doesn't need to be a set but I think most of the time it is.
"if the array items are not just strings but complex structures that match in some parts but not in others" then they are not the same. It's only going to remove same ones.
Thanks for noticing that. I edited it to make it more clear.

Right now if I want to achieve the example I need to do something like this (maybe there's an easy way but I figured this out of the manual):
del(.background.type) | del(.permissions[] | select . == "unlimitedStorage")
Let's say tomorrow I'm gonna need to remove some an odd object and I can't produce the code to remove it.
These are fixed objetcs. They are not objects that are constantly produced randomly like logs of things in real life, for example database table of issues on GitHub.
